# Redhat: .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redhat

In codeignitor .htaccess not working on redhat server the same .htaccess is working perfectly on local server ie xampp
also changed 'AllowOverride None' to 'AllowOverride All' . Please give answer with respective to 'redhat' only.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

phpinfo() shows
[Apache Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpEMe.jpg)

Comment: redhat? is your OS and not your Webserver! So htaccess deals with apache and not with redhat

Comment: opps! but please provide me answer.

Comment: check if mod_rewrite is enabled ... etc

Comment: how can i check it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite module seems to be loaded from your screenshot.
you can also enable .htaccess from within your VirtualHost by adding this stanza:

```
  #Enable readin .htaccess
  <Directory "/var/www/html/mysite">
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your .htaccess file is not working on a Red Hat server, there are a few things you can check and adjust. Here are some steps to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

**Verify mod_rewrite Module:**

Make sure that the mod_rewrite module is enabled on your Apache server. You can do this by running the following command:

```
sudo apachectl -M | grep rewrite
```

If the module is not listed, you may need to enable it. On Red Hat-based systems, you can use:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

After enabling the module, restart Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

**Check AllowOverride Settings:**

As you mentioned, you already changed the AllowOverride directive. Ensure that the changes are made in the correct configuration file. On Red Hat systems, the Apache configuration is typically found in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.

Open the Apache configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Locate the  section that corresponds to your web directory, and make sure it has the following or similar lines:

apache:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

After making changes, restart Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

**Check .htaccess File Location:**
Ensure that your .htaccess file is located in the root directory of your CodeIgniter application.

**Verify RewriteBase in .htaccess:**
In your .htaccess file, you can try adding or modifying the RewriteBase directive. For example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /your-subdirectory-if-any/
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Adjust the RewriteBase to match the subdirectory structure of your application.

**Check Apache Error Logs:**

Check the Apache error logs for any messages related to the .htaccess file. The error log location can vary, but it is often found in /var/log/httpd/error_log. Look for any errors or warnings that might indicate the source of the problem.

> sudo tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log

After making these adjustments, your .htaccess file should work as expected on your Red Hat server. If you encounter further issues, reviewing the Apache error logs can provide additional insights into the problem.

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)